# WEB API is not getting parameter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i am calling a web api in the below given manner

```
 $scope.workOrder = {};
 $scope.workOrder.assignedName = "Dummy"
 dbSrvc.getDatFromService('../../api/DispatchNotifyService/GetWorkOrders', $scope.workOrder).then(function (result) {
    $scope.workOrderList = result.data;
    $scope.workOrderNumberLabel = $scope.workOrderList[0].workOrderNumber;
    $scope.workOrderpriority = $scope.workOrderList[0].priority;
    $scope.getEmployeeDetailsDO(null);
});
```

API is called but parameter is not getting the value.Its value is null always.
I am using angular js for calling the web API. Please help me out in this.

This is my server code.

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ICollection<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrders(WorkOrder workOrder)
    {
        this.Initialize();
        List<string> lstWorkOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(this.sessionObject.WorkOrderDetails);
        ICollection<WorkOrder> workOrderCollection = new Collection<WorkOrder>();

        lstWorkOrder.ToList().ForEach(delegate(string wo)
        {
            WorkOrder workOrderDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkOrder>(wo);
            workOrderCollection.Add(workOrderDetails);
        });

        return workOrderCollection;
    }
```

Comment: What does: `dbSrvc.getDatFromService` do? Post the code for it

Comment: show the `WorkOrder` model code